# Migrating from mysql to oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c

I'm migrating from MySQL to oracle i got the script generated on MySQL and when creating a view MySQL add this:

```
 Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "TB"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 114
               Right = 189
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
      Begin ColumnWidths = 9
         Width = 284
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 11
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 900
         Table = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
```

I have created the view with no problem on oracle
but since i´m new on oracle i don't know if this code is necessary or its just necessary on MySQL, if it is necessary how can i get it done on oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like the extended properties for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which are added to the view so your GUI Design layout will be loaded again if you open that view again in the GUI - but you said you are doing MySQL to Oracle not SQL Server to Oracle so not sure why you are using SSMS.

This isn't required for the view to work (in any database) only to set the layout of the designer view in SSMS so there is no need to add it into your Oracle view.

If you use `Tasks -> Generate Scripts` to export your `VIEW` code via SSMS you can disable scripting of extended properties in the Advanced Options by setting `Script Extended Properties` to `false`.